# How to execute this asynchronous operation in parallel

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, .net-4.7.2

In my application, I have a method like this:

```
private async Task LoadDataSetsAsyncOld()
{
    if (Cache["QISRUID317"+Session.SessionID]==null)
    {
        using (IParameterProviderBusinessLogic parameterProviderBusiness
            = new ParameterProviderBusinessLogic())
        {
            dataSet = await parameterProviderBusiness.GetOutlierParametersAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        
            using (ILocationProviderBusinessLogic _locationProviderBusinessLogic
                = new LocationProviderBusinessLogic(
                    (BusinessLogicBase)parameterProviderBusiness))
            {
                dataSet.Merge(await _locationProviderBusinessLogic
                    .GetLocationProviderAsync());
            }

            using (ISamplePointProviderBusinessLogic _samplePointProviderBusinessLogic
                = new SamplePointProviderBusinessLogic(
                    (BusinessLogicBase)parameterProviderBusiness))
            {
                dataSet.Merge(await _samplePointProviderBusinessLogic
                    .GetSamplePointProviderAsync());
            }

            using (IPMDOperationsProviderBusinessLogic operationsProviderDataAccess
                = new PMDOperationsProviderBusinessLogic(
                    (BusinessLogicBase)parameterProviderBusiness))
            {
                dataSet.Merge(await operationsProviderDataAccess
                    .GetPMDOperationsAsync());
            }

            using (IMethodOfMeasureProviderBusinessLogic
                methodOfMeasureProviderBusinessLogic
                = new MethodOfMeasureProviderBusinessLogic(
                    (BusinessLogicBase)parameterProviderBusiness))
            {
                dataSet.Merge(await methodOfMeasureProviderBusinessLogic
                    .GetMethodOfMeasureAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
            }

            using (IPackerProviderBusinessLogic packerProviderBusinessLogic
                = new PackerProviderBusinessLogic(
                    (BusinessLogicBase)parameterProviderBusiness))
            {
                DataSet packerDs = await packerProviderBusinessLogic
                    .GetPackerProviderAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                packerDs.Relations.RemoveAt(0);
                packerDs.AcceptChanges();
                dataSet.Merge(packerDs);
            }

            using (IFilterTypeProviderBusinessLogic filterTypeProviderBusinessLogic
                = new FilterTypeProviderBusinessLogic(
                    (BusinessLogicBase)parameterProviderBusiness))
            {
                dataSet.Merge(await filterTypeProviderBusinessLogic
                    .GetFilterTypeProviderAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
            }

            using (IFilterMakerProviderBusinessLogic _filterMakerProviderBusinessLogic
                = new FilterMakerProviderBusinessLogic(
                    (BusinessLogicBase)parameterProviderBusiness))
            {
                DataSet dsMaker = await _filterMakerProviderBusinessLogic
                    .GetFilterMakerProviderAsync();
                dsMaker.Relations.RemoveAt(0);
                dsMaker.AcceptChanges();
                dataSet.Merge(dsMaker);
            }
        }

        Cache["QISRUID317" + Session.SessionID] = dataSet;
    }
}
```

I need to enhance the performance, so I planned to use `Task.WhenAll()` to execute the tasks in the method concurrently.

But how can I do it, is it possible to do so, and is it good practice?

Comment: What .NET platform are you targeting? .NET 7?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias 4.7.2 , please help

Comment: Help with what? What do those methods do? Blindly trying to "parallelize" stuff can often lead to far worse performance. If you access the same database over the same network, running 10 expensive queries in parallel will result in far worse than 100 slower performance as the queries can end up blocking each other. You'll still have to transfer the data over the same network, but this time with 1/10th the bandwidth

Comment: As for good practices, using DataSet is not a good practice. It's not a Python DataFrame. In this case it doesn't seem to be needed at all. If you want to cache lookup data a better option is to just cache that data individually. If you want to combine all of them, you can use a `Dictionary<string,Whatever>` or an object with properties. Finally, instead of loading data into DataTables you can load them into lists of items or any other collection suitable for what you need. A `Dictionary<string,Country>` is far better for lookups than a table with country names and data

Comment: If you only want to load a small amount of lookup data, you can improve performance by batching all commands and executing them as a single batch, over a single connection.

Comment: Rooter how about [Serg's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75670053/11178549) answer? Is it helpful? If not, why?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

var dataSetTask = parameterProviderBusiness.GetOutlierParametersAsync()
                                                 .ConfigureAwait(false);

using (var _locationProviderBusinessLogic = new LocationProviderBusinessLogic(
                                         (BusinessLogicBase)parameterProviderBusiness))
using (var _samplePointProviderBusinessLogic = new SamplePointProviderBusinessLogic(
                                         (BusinessLogicBase)parameterProviderBusiness))
//other usings here
{
    var locationProviderTask = _locationProviderBusinessLogic
                                                .GetLocationProviderAsync();
    tasks.Add(locationProviderTask);

    var samplePointProviderTask = _samplePointProviderBusinessLogic
                                                .GetSamplePointProviderAsync();
    tasks.Add(samplePointProviderTask);

    //other requests here: run task, store task in variable and add into the list

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    dataSet.Merge(await locationProviderTask);
    dataSet.Merge(await samplePointProviderTask);
    //other merges and results processing here.
}
```